# Problem with commiting a String to a Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a ModalBottomSheet, which opens a lot of RaisedButtons. These buttons should change there Color after pressing.
Therefore I created a StatefulWidget named "Buttons".

In my MainClass i use
 `for (String item in myList) Buttons(item)`

to commit the Strings of myList to Buttons.

But i have 2 Problems in Buttons:

1. `String item` should be final, but then i can't use it as a setter
   (I want to get rid of the blue underlining of Buttons, which tell me: This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: )
2. The other problem is, that in my buildMethod "item" isn't defined.
   Why can't I use `String item` in my build Method?

```
 class Buttons extends StatefulWidget {
  String item;
  Buttons(String item) {
    this.item = item;
  }

  @override
  _ButtonsState createState() => _ButtonsState();
}

class _ButtonsState extends State<Buttons> {
  bool pressAttention = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text(item),
          color: pressAttention ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () => setState(() => pressAttention = !pressAttention),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Text(item)` by `Text(widget.item)`

```dart
class Buttons extends StatefulWidget {
  final String item;
  Buttons(this.item);

  @override
  _ButtonsState createState() => _ButtonsState();
}

class _ButtonsState extends State<Buttons> {
  bool pressAttention = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text(widget.item),
          color: pressAttention ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () => setState(() => pressAttention = !pressAttention),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But its not really clear to me why it works like this

Comment: That's because you are in the `state` of your `widget`, but not in your `widget`.